# Example of operator with $\lVert T \rVert^ i = 1$ in normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let X be a normed vector space of your choice with its norm $\lVert.\rVert$. I am looking for an operator of norm $\lVert T \rVert  ^ i = 1$.

Defined on as $T:X \rightarrow X$ s.t. its powers $T^{i} = T \circ T^{i-1}$ for all $i \geq 1$.

Here is where I am having trouble though, it needs to have $T^{i} \neq T^{i-1}$

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Surely you mean $\lVert T^i\rVert = 1$, not $\lVert T\rVert^i = 1$?  Anyway, just take an irrational rotation on $X = \mathbb C$.

Comment: [Shift operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator)

Comment: @LSpice, that’s how it is written out in the problem. Thank you for your contribution. Thanks to the user in the comment bellow as well!

Comment: As written, the condition $\|T\|^i = 1$ (for some/all $i$) is equivalent to $\|T\| = 1$, as $\|T\| \ge 0$.

Comment: You can take $T=-Id$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven You came up with the simlpest example!